# Spring RabbitMQ - caching multiple channels per connection?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

the default caching strategy using Spring AMQP is to create a single connection with multiple channels. The number of created channels depends on the concurrency of the listeners.

This creates an issue for us because we have lots of listeners with a concurrency of only a few consumers. Rabbit [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#resource-usage) recommends using a single-digit number of channels per connection.

When we have a few listeners, let's say 10, and each of them needs a concurrency of 5. This creates a single connection with 50 channels which is far more than recommended.

I have tried playing with `spring.rabbitmq.cache` properties but I cannot figure out how to set it up so each listener uses its own connection with 5 channels. I would prefer to create 10 connections with 5 channels over 1 with 50.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to give each container its own connection factory.

You can add a `ContainerCustomizer` to the container factory and use it to change the connection factory for each container. It will be called after the container is created and before it is started.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64913992Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64913992Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo", concurrency = "5")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "bar", concurrency = "5")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}

@Component
class Customizer {

    Customizer(GenericApplicationContext context, CachingConnectionFactory cf,
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory) {

        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            CachingConnectionFactory newCf = new CachingConnectionFactory(cf.getRabbitConnectionFactory());
            String name = "cf." + container.getQueueNames()[0];
            newCf.setConnectionNameStrategy(c -> name);
            // set any other CCF properties you need
            context.registerBean(name, CachingConnectionFactory.class, () -> newCf);
            context.getBean(name); // initialize
            container.setConnectionFactory(newCf);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to create new instances of `CachingConnectionFactory` like they are created in Spring Boots `RabbitAutoConfiguration`?